# Python- Remove characters then join into string

Tags: python, text-processing

I'm writing a program to convert standard SVG paths to Raphael.js friendly format.

The path data is in the format

```
d="M 62.678745,
   259.31235 L 63.560745,
   258.43135 L 64.220745,
   257.99135 L 64.439745,
   258.43135 L 64.000745
     ...
     ...
   "
```

What I'd like to do is first remove the decimal digits, then remove the whitespace.  The end result should be in the format

```
d="M62,
   259L63,
   258L64,
   257L64,
   258L64
     ...
     ...
   "
```

I have about 2000 or so of these paths to parse and transform into a JSON file.

What I've gotten done so far is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

svg = open("/path/to/file.svg", "r").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg)
paths = soup.findAll("path")

raphael = []

for p in paths:
  splitData = p['d'].split(",")
  tempList = []

    for s in splitData:
      #strip decimals from string
      #don't know how to do this

      #remove whitespace
      s.replace(" ", "")

      #add to templist
      tempList.append(s + ", ")

    tempList[-1].replace(", ", "")
    raphael.append(tempList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

svg = open("/path/to/file.svg", "r").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg)
paths = soup.findAll("path")

raphael = []

for p in paths:
    splitData = p['d'].split(",")
    for line in splitData:
        # Remove ".000000" part
        line = re.sub("\.\d*", "", line)
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        raphael.append(line)

d = ",\n".join(raphael)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> d="""M 62.678745,
   259.31235 L 63.560745,
   258.43135 L 64.220745,
   257.99135 L 64.439745,
   258.43135 L 64.000745"""

for strs in d.splitlines():
    print  re.sub(r'(\s+)|(\.\d+)','',strs)
...     
M62,
259L63,
258L64,
257L64,
258L64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a brute force parser:

```
def isint(x):
    try:
        int(float(x))
        return True
    except:
        return False

def parser(s):
    mystr = lambda x: str(int(float(x)))
    s = s.replace('\n','##')
    tmp = ','.join( [''.join([mystr(x) if isint(x) else x \
                         for x in j.split()]) \
                         for j in s.split(',')] )
    return tmp.replace('##', '\n')
```

Testing:

```
d="M 62.678745,\n 259.31235 L 63.560745,\n 258.43135 L 64.220745, \n 257.99135 L 64.439745, \n 258.43135 L 64.000745 "
print parser(d)
# M62,
# 259L63,
# 258L64,
# 257L64,
# 258L64
```

Comment: Don't you think this is an overkill? It can be easily done by `re.sub(r'(\s+)|(\.\d+)','',line)`